# Confusing Hovereffct

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I've created this navigationbar: http://cdpn.io/tdnfv (with the help of two tutorials, I cant post the links here due to my low reputation, the links are on codepen)

Now as you can see, the blue bar is moving nicely, and is perfectly under Item 6, but there is an increasing "disharmony" towards Item6. 
I am not able to identify the piece of code which is responsible of this! Also am I not sure how to change the "default location" of the moving bar, means the position when there are no hover events.

I would really appreciate some help, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the little white spaces in between each `<li>`. There are different ways of dealing with this, but my favorite is to remove the font size, then restore it in the element that actually contains the text.

```
ul {
    font-size: 0;
}
ul li a {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

P.S., that's a really neat concept.

Comment: Thank you! Finally a solution...
And where does it define the wait position of the blue bar? Is that easy to change or do I need (which I am afraid off) to change the whole structure?

Comment: It's the transition on `ul li a`

Comment: I wasn't able to change the location... Even if I remove the hole transition, it doesn't happen anything. Can you change the default location with a new class to a new item? 
Like this: ul li active { ... }

Comment: Sorry, it's both that and `ul li:last-child a::after`